# Why the buffer provided by SDL2, for audio samples, is not big enough?

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

I use SDL2 to create sound with format:

```
freq = 32 * 1500;
format = AUDIO_F32SYS;
channels = 1;
samples = 1500;
```

I expect length parameter in my callback to be 6000 (`1 * sizeof(float) * 1500`) but it is 3000.

I've tried to decrease sample count, use 2 channels, but always provided buffer is as half big as needed.

This is how I open audio device:

```
SDL_AudioSpec want, have;
SDL_zero(want);
want.freq = 32 * 1500;
want.format = AUDIO_F32SYS;
want.channels = 1;
want.samples = 1500;
want.callback = ::PlayDing;
want.userdata = this;
m_Audio = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(nullptr, 0, &want, &have, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);
// want == have here
```

All fields of `want` and `have` are equal.

This problem started to happen after I switched from Ubuntu to Debian on the same laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong assumption that each time the callback gets called it should fill `samples` amount of audio data.

The number of samples that callback needs to provide should be calculated inside callback based on `length / sizeof(float)`.